# 4G signal on phone, but showing LTE on my MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, tethering

Usually, the signal strength on the iPhone is the same with the one shown on my MacBook:

> [image]

However, in a specific area, between two hills, where the signal is pretty poor, my iPhone shows 1 circle of 4G signal (and the internet does work pretty well on the iPhone), but my MacBook shows 1 circle of LTE signal, and it's very slow.

Is there any setting that I can change to make the MacBook internet via Hotspot faster?

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading about 4G vs LTE, I found LTE includes 4G. So, technically it's correct.

And sometimes, even it shows 4G on my MacBook, it's still slow. It seems to be just the naming.